# SQL lite import csv error CREATE TABLE data;(...) failed: near ";": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, csv, import-csv

Brand new to SQL lite, running on a mac. I'm trying to import a csv file from the SQL lite tutorial:
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

The 'cities' data I'm trying to import for the tutorial is here:
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/city.csv

I try and run the following code from Terminal to import the data into a database named 'data' and get the following error:

```
sqlite3    
.mode csv    
.import cities.csv data;    

CREATE TABLE data;(...) failed: near ";": syntax error
```

A possible explanation may be the way I'm downloading the data - I copied the data from the webpage into TextWrangler and saved it as a .txt file. I then manually changed the extension to .csv. This doesn't seem very eloquent but that was the advice I found online for creating the .csv file: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7857007
If this is the issue then how can I resolve it? If not then where am I going wrong?

Another potentially useful point - when I executed the code yesterday there was no problem, it created a database with the data. However, running the same code today produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 dot commands such as `.import` are not SQL and don't need semicolon at end. Replace

```
.import cities.csv data;
```

with

```
.import cities.csv data
```